# Sort adapter in android

Tags: android, listview

I would like to know how I can sort this adapter:

```
private class ProductsListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

        public ProductsListAdapter() {
            super();

        }

        public int getCount() {
            return SingletonComparer.getInstance().getProducts().size();
        }

        public Object getItem(int position) {
            return SingletonComparer.getInstance().getProducts().get(position);
        }

        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return SingletonComparer.getInstance().getProducts().get(position).getId();
        }

        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
                TextView textView = getGenericView();
                textView.setText(SingletonComparer.getInstance().getProducts().get(position)
                        .getName());
                TextView textView2 = getGenericView();
                textView2.setText(""
                        + SingletonComparer.getInstance().getProducts()
                                .get(position).getPrice());
                TextView textView3 = getGenericView();


                textView3.setText(SingletonData.getInstance().getBrandName(SingletonComparer.getInstance().getProducts().get(position)
                        .getBrandID()));

                LinearLayout ll = new LinearLayout(getActivity());
                ll.addView(textView, new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(0,
                        LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 1.0f));
                ll.addView(textView2, 1, new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(0,
                        LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 1.0f));
                ll.addView(textView3, 2, new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(0,
                        LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 1.0f));
                ll.setId(SingletonComparer.getInstance().getProducts().get(position)
                        .getId());
                return ll;

        }
    }
```

by field

```
SingletonComparer.getInstance().getProducts()
                                    .get(position).getPrice());
```

This is possible? If yes How I can do that?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use a **Comparator** to sort listed items.

You could do something like this:

```
public class SortByPrice implements Comparator{

    public int compare(Object o1, Object o2) {
        Product p1 = (Product) o1;
        Product p2 = (Product) o2; 
        // return -1, 0, 1 to determine less than, equal to or greater than
        return (p1.getPrice() > p2.getPrice() ? 1 : (p1.getPrice() == p2.getPrice() ? 0 : -1));
        // **or** the previous return statement can be simplified to:
        return p1.getPrice() - p2.getPrice();
    }
}
```

You will not want to perform this in your `getView()` method, instead doing it **when the data is added to your adapter** by doing a sort on the list, so as it is in order from the very beginning.

So just before your add your data to the list, call:

```
Collections.sort(list, new SortByPrice());
```

Which will take care of sorting your data with the **Comparator** you created.

Comment: I get error in this line:  'return p1.getPrice() > p2.getPrice();' to change return to boolean. When I change int on boolean I get error to change on int. Why?

Comment: Good spot, have updated the example above to return an int value. The compare method uses the priciples of greater than, equal to and less than, typically returned as -1, 0 or 1 to determine whether something is the same as or should be put above/below in the list

Comment: Simply return a difference, not only -1, 0, 1: return p1.getPrice() - p2.getPrice();

Comment: @CoolMind that will definitely work, and is a better higher level approach. Returning -1, 0, 1 demonstrates how it works on a more fundamental level, but will add your suggestion to the main answer

Answer (score 1):

You cannot sort adapter. You should sort your data source (which I expect to be handled in your `SingletonComparer` class)

BTW: you should refactor your code, store reference to `SingletonComparer` in adapter's member instead of continuosly doing `SingletonComparer.getInstance().getProducts()`.